# Assiging width and height property as of screen in css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

How can assign width and height value in css as the width and height of screen respectively. I tried with below css but now working for me.

```
.classname
 {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
 }
```

**EDIT**

I have used Jquery code too as

```
 $("#PanelGrid").width = $(window).width();
```

But does not work.

Here is the code.

```
<table style="font-family: calibri; height: 100%;" border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    width="100%">

   <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Calibri">
            <div id="PanelGrid" style="overflow:auto;"> </td>
   <tr></table>
```

Please help.

Comment: By "screen", you mean the browser window?

Comment: CSS can't return in any way the exact with or height. You'll need to do it with javascript or use mediaqueries to build your design for different screen sizes.

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard : Using '$("#PanelGrid").width = $(window).width();' Not work for me. Can you explain more please

Comment: Eraj, you should post your code (html, css, js) so we can see exactly what you want. There are many ways to handle width and height.

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard : Can you look at the code

Comment: Ok, now we have your code, can you let us know which part exactly should have the screen width and height, the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element with the class .classname has a parent, it will use 100% of the *parent element's* height and width instead of the browser window's.

Try forcing it with absolute positioning, [like in this example](http://andrewpeace.com/css-full-screen-div.html).

Answer (score 1):

Percentage height in CSS is a funny thing. Go to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b5ww2/5/ and try doing the following:

1.

```
#div1 {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}​
```

2.

```
#div1 {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}​
```

3.

```
#div1 {
    height: 100%;
}​
```

4.

```
#div1 {
    height: 50%;
}​
```

You should see the results: when positioning is normal (static), the percentage height of an element is in fact in relation to the height of its parent. When you use absolute positioning, the viewport (screen) acts as the parent of the element and you can use percentage height as you would expect.

So, if you know the height of the element's containing block in relation to the absolute height of the viewport, can simply adjust the percentage height accordingly. Otherwise, you might need to use absolute positioning and deal with the ensuing side effects.

Comment: It is not working. I am using div in td which has width 100%.

Comment: What isn't working? What did you try? Please post some code or give me some idea how to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a div use up the full height and width of the window and to *always* use the full height/width even if the browser size is changed, you could try:

```
.classname {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

this will place the outer bounds of the container against the edges of viewport.

Hope that helps.